# Magento admin login issue

Tags: php, magento, authentication

I have just installed magento cms on my PC but it can't log me in. Even I have checked all the login credentials. So anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi, this is better suitable for Magento's support resources.

Comment: There's a magento beta stackexchange site now, see http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: what error are you getting, check magento error log

Answer (score 2):

It is simple.

It cannot 'store' the cookie.

Make a virtual host with a dot .

or if that is difficult access it via lo 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1

ideally, it is a good approach to have a virtual host configured to run magento. Virtual host can be : `mysite.local` pointing towards `/var/www/magento`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It is snot neccessary to make virtual host for magento on local

Comment: It may not be necessary but, it is recommended. Not just Magento but, any project which you manage should have a FQDN-style

Answer (score 0):

please check your url it should not be localhost instead of that use 127.0.0.1.It may work